# How to close socket on activity termination in android?

Tags: android, sockets, udp

My question is how to close socket on the end of activity if it is opened with syntax:

```
        serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(PORT);
        serverSocket.setBroadcast(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put `serverSocket.close()` in `onPause()` method of your activity

```
@Override 
public void onPause(){
    ...
    serverSocket.close();   
    ...
}
```

Comment: I would do it in onPause() , because onDestroy() is not always called.  And os course reopen it in onResume()